# Spring websocket Server and unity3d client

Tags: spring, unity-game-engine, websocket, socket.io

i'm using the spring web socket , it's a chat web socket app, every user msg will be delivered to all users, this below my home.html

```
    function connect() {

    var socket = new SockJS('http://192.168.1.115:8080/ROOT/hello');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting) {
            console.log(greeting);
            console.log("greetinggggggggg");
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}

function disconnect() {
    if (stompClient != null) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}

function sendName() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({
        'name' : name
    }));
}
```

I want to use a unity3d app as client, actually i'm using socket io to connect to a web socket endpoint.

socket io link on assets store https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721

i could connect to the endpoint but i could not find how to subscribe to /topic/greetings as

```
 stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                console.log(greeting);
                console.log("greetinggggggggg");
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a tough time using that library, or any others I have come across.